# Emulator that emulates arm hardware

Tags: x86, arm, qemu, emulation

I want to hook arm instructions as they executes but most of the emulators are based on VirtualBox that uses houdini to translate arm instructions to x86, and i really can't hook a native JNI lib, moreover I'm doing a instruction trace please suggest a emulator that does it.

Comment: https://github.com/qilingframework/qiling

Comment: hi bruh thanks for this, but i need a emulator that can run games so i can trace things this isnt graphical